# Sum different subtotals from different function math operations. (I've put a snippet)

Tags: javascript

### Edit: Z-Bone helped! All the problem was solved by moving the script to the end of the html. So, if you have any problem similar, try moving script position!

I've made a minimal representation from my code. Basically I need a function to sum subtotal 1 + subtotal 2. Tried many things, but couldn't achieved my objective. It seems simple, I know, but I'm trying to learn by my self.

Resume:

- Subtotal 1: sum values by marking checkboxes
- Subtotal 2: multiplicate values insertes in 'box1' by 188 ('box2')
- Total: Subtotal 1 + Subtotal 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var total = 0;
 
 function test(item) {

 if (item.checked){
    total += parseInt(item.value);
}
 else {
    total -= parseInt(item.value);
}
    document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + "";
}
  function multi() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
}
 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<br>

<hr>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif""" color="rebeccapurple" size="4">
<center><b>Subtotal 1:</b></font><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif""" color="red" size="5"> R$ <span id="Totalcost"></span></font></b></center>
<hr>

<form action="orcamento.php" method="post">

<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="black" size="3">

<table style="width:80%" class="table">
<tr>
<th style="width: 267px"></th>
<th></th> 
<th style="width: 267px"></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  
    <td style="width: 267px">
<input id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" value="91" onClick="test(this);" />
<label for="checkbox-1">Service 1</label>
 </td>

    <td>R$ 91,00</td>

 <td style="width: 267px">
<input id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-2" input type="checkbox" value="19" onClick="test(this);" />
<label for="checkbox-2">Service 2</label>
 </td>

 <td>R$ 19,00</td>

</tr>

</table>

</font>

<br>

 <tr>
    Quantidade de funcionarios<td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="multi()" style="width:40px;" /></td>
<br><br> 
    Valor por funcionario<td><input id="box2" type="text" value="188" readonly style="width:40px;" /></td>
<br><br>
    Subtotal 2: R$ <td><input id="result" style="width:50px;" readonly /></td>
 </tr>
 
<br>
<br>

Total: <input id="z" type="text" readonly />

<br>

<br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was the following:

1. Create vars pointing to the `subtotal1` and `subtotal2` elements
2. Create a function `sumSubtotals` that takes both values and sums them. Notice that I tested to see if a number exists in the input of both subtotals, otherwise I set it to 0.
3. Call the `sumSubtotals` function from the `mutli` and `test` functions. Since these are the funcitons that actually change the subtotals

And here is the snippet:

```js
var total = 0;

var subtotal1 = document.getElementById('Totalcost');
var subtotal2 = document.getElementById('result');

function test(item) {

 if (item.checked) {
  total += parseInt(item.value);
 } else {
  total -= parseInt(item.value);
 }
 document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + "";
 sumSubtotals(subtotal1.innerText, subtotal2.value);
}
function multi() {
 var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
 var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
 var result = document.getElementById('result');
 var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
 result.value = myResult;
 sumSubtotals(subtotal1.innerText, subtotal2.value);
}

function sumSubtotals(subtotal1, subtotal2) {
 var total = document.getElementById('z');
 subtotal1 = isNaN(parseInt(subtotal1)) ? 0 : subtotal1;
 subtotal2 = isNaN(parseInt(subtotal2)) ? 0 : subtotal2;
 total.value = parseFloat(subtotal1) + parseFloat(subtotal2);
}
```

```html
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" "" color="rebeccapurple" size="4">
        <center><b>Subtotal 1:</b></font><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif""" color="red" size="5"> R$ <span id="Totalcost"></span></font></b></center>
    <hr>
    <form action="orcamento.php" method="post">
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="black" size="3">
            <table style="width:80%" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 267px"></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="width: 267px"></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 267px">
                        <input id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" value="91" onClick="test(this);" />
                        <label for="checkbox-1">Service 1</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>R$ 91,00</td>
                    <td style="width: 267px">
                        <input id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-2" input type="checkbox" value="19" onClick="test(this);" />
                        <label for="checkbox-2">Service 2</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>R$ 19,00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </font>
        <br>
        <tr>
            Quantidade de funcionarios
            <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="multi()" style="width:40px;" /></td>
            <br><br> Valor por funcionario
            <td><input id="box2" type="text" value="188" readonly style="width:40px;" /></td>
            <br><br> Subtotal 2: R$
            <td><input id="result" style="width:50px;" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <br> Total: <input id="z" type="text" readonly />
```

Comment: Hi Z-Bone! Thanks for the reply! You've explained very well! I've tried something similar last day and it didn't work. Tried your code and incredibly it didn't work either (and I saw your snippet working). I thought it could be "for some reason" my css code causing problem, but it's not. I've double checked the html code, and coudn't see a problem. Here is a print-screen: http://i.imgur.com/XR0AWdU.jpg

Comment: Do you have any errors in the web console? Maybe you changed something in the HTML?

Comment: Hi man! I made a lot of tests, including copying and organizing everything in a new file, and the "total" keep not showing numbers. It's incredible hahaha What do you think it could be in your experience?

Comment: Try to include the javascript at the end of the html and see if that works.. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2t22pj8L/1/

Comment: HI Z-Bone! Man, follow your advice. Without changing anything, I've just move the script to the end of html and now it Works! Incredible! I've tried so many things and was just the position of the script hahahaha Man, thanks a lot for that. Really thanks!